# Inserting and Selecting Date (Java) (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, jdbc

I have a table where I have to do a `SELECT ... BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`, as well as insert `Date` values into the same table.

I read things like:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
pStmt.setDate( 1, new java.sql.Date( now.getTime() ) );
pStmt.setTimestamp( 2, new java.sql.Timestamp( now.getTime() ) );
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

But that kind of code sets or gets the current date, doesn't it? I want to insert and select custom dates myself.

I also read it here at *[StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)*:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ( YEAR(myfield) = '2009')
  AND ( MONTH(myfield) = '1')
```

Is it also possible to make the `Date` fields `String`, then use `StringTokenizer` to extract only the day, month or year information and use them in a `SELECT` similar to this code? (In case my first - and simpler - idea is impossible.)

So until now, there's two possible solutions. I also need to know which one is faster since the database accessed is in a fail-safe / critical system (a bank) with lots of data.

Comment: What do you mean by *custom dates*? Can you give a concrete example of what you want (*are the start_date and end_date timestamps in your DB*)?

Comment: Your examples are using the current date/time.  If that's all you want, let MySQL do it for you, e.g.  `NOW()`.  If not, tell us what kind of date range you're after.

Comment: Also note that `YEAR(myfield)` is a function on the field, and mysql won't be able to use an index to get the data quickly.

Comment: It must select already inserted dates, then populate a table to be generated into PDF (I'm using iText).

I wish to insert a past date so all my tables would be according to the same example.

Comment: About the 2nd idea, I was thinking about that:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (YEAR(st_year)=?) AND (MONTH(st_month)=?) AND (DAY(st_day)=?);(...)etc(...) String slash, data, st_year, st_month, st_day; StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(slash, "/"); data = st.nextToken(); day = data; (...)etc(...)

Comment: P.S. The SQL code above would be in the Java program. We won't use the database directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is better, because you were able to use date functions to manipulate values.

```
private void executeQuery(java.util.Date startDate, java.util.Date endDate) throws SQLException {
  Connection conn = null;
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  try {
    conn = getConnection();
    String query = "select ... between ? and ?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()));
    pstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));
    //return results
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    rs.last();
    System.out.println("last row = " + rs.getRow());
  } finally {
    if (pstmt != null) {
      pstmt.close();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks.

Now, how the value of a Date field (that is, I must input the date, not use the current one) could feed a PreparedStatement? Like in "pStmt.setString(1,myString)".